# dojo XhrPost fails with Safari 5.1.1

Tags: servlets, safari, dojo

I have been building a website and using it on Chrome, however for completeness I have been testing on Safari. Everything works fine except the one dojo.xhrPost method that I use.

```
    function openAlbumPage(title)
    {
        dojo.xhrPost(
        {
           url: "/getAlbum?title="+title,
           handleAs: "text"
        });
        window.open("album.html","_self");
    }
```

Which should call the following post method from a servlet:

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    queryTitle = request.getParameter("title");
    }
```

However the servlet never gets called. As stated above, this works fine in Chrome. Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: what happens if you comment out `window.open(..)`?  Due to the asynchronous nature of `xhrPost`, I wonder if safari isn't fully executing the post before loading the new page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to have fixed itself. Did nothing other then run the code a couple of days later and everything is working fine. Thanks for the input BuffaloBuffalo.